# Uniserial modules for group algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, group-algebras

Recall that a module is uniserial in case it has a unique composition series.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $kG$ its group algebra, that we assume is not semi-simple.

> Questions:
> Can uniserial modules be classified over group algebras?
>
> Is it known when there are only finitely many uniserial modules? (probably this rarely happens).

In case the group admits a cyclic $p$-Sylow subgroup (p the characteristic of the field), the group algebra is representation finite and there are only finitely many uniserial modules.
In case the group admits a cyclic normal $p$-Sylow subgroup then any indecomposable module is uniserial (im not sure about the converse of this but it should be false or else it would answer an open question).

Comment: Do you have the answer in a few cases (e.g., when $G$ is abelian)?

Comment: @YCor I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, what about $G$ abelian non-cyclic of order $p^2$? Do you know a single case where there are infinitely many uniserial modules?

Comment: @YCor I dont know, but I would think that usually group algebras have infinitely many uniserial modules.

Comment: Actually any finite group with quotient $C_p^2$ is clearly with infinitely many non-isomorphic 2-dimensional uniserial $kG$-modules (for $k$ infinite of characteristic $p$). Indeed one can assume $G=C_p^2$. Then $A=kG$ is local and, denoting by $M$ its maximal ideal (=augmentation ideal), we have $\dim_k(M/M^2)\ge 2$ (indeed $\dim_k(M/M^2)=1$ would imply $\dim(A)=\dim(A/M^p)=p$). Hence, the $A/(M^2+I)$, when $I$ ranges over hyperplanes of $M/M^2$, form $|K|$ pairwise non-isomorphic 2-dimensional uniserial $kG$-modules. This completely settles the abelian case, and also the nilpotent case.

Comment: The first open case would therefore be $G=\mathrm{Alt}_4$ in characteristic $2$.

Comment: @YCor Is there a non-representation-finite group algebra over an infinite field with only finitely many length two-dimensional indecomposable representations? In general it seems to be an interesting question when a finite dimensional algebra has only finitely many indecomposable length 2 representations.